# Convert rows into columns more than 2 columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I want to convert rows into columns using pivot. If it has only two columns, we can do that. Is it possible we can pivot if the table have more than 2 columns?

For example:

```
    C1  C2      C3
________________________ 
    A   10      1000
    B   20      1000 
    C   30      1500
```

Expected output:

```
A         B        C
10        20       30
1000      1000     1500
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

This is the one way i found even you can try with one pivot instead of using complex cte's

```
WITH cte
         AS (SELECT Max(a) a,
                    Max(b) b,
                    Max(c) c
             FROM   (SELECT *
                     FROM   #Table1)a
                    PIVOT ( Avg(c2)
                          FOR c1 IN (a,
                                     b,
                                     c) ) AS c),
         c2
         AS (SELECT Max(a) a,
                    Max(b) b,
                    Max(c) c
             FROM   (SELECT *
                     FROM   #Table1)a
                    PIVOT ( Avg(c3)
                          FOR c1 IN (a,
                                     b,
                                     c) ) AS c3) SELECT *
    FROM   cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM   c2
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple way using PIVOT and a Table Value Constructor

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
    ([C1] varchar(1), [C2] int, [C3] int)
;

INSERT INTO myTable
    ([C1], [C2], [C3])
VALUES
    ('A', 10, 1000),
    ('B', 20, 1000),
    ('C', 30, 1500)
;


SELECT  [A],[B],[C] 
FROM    (
        SELECT  ca.*
        FROM    myTable mt
                CROSS APPLY (VALUES(mt.C1, 1, mt.C2),(mt.C1, 2, mt.C3)) ca(col, rn, val)
        ) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(val)
    FOR col IN ([A],[B],[C])
) p
```

the Cross Apply will create a new row for each column (C2, C3)  `col` is the C1 value (A,B,C)  `rn` is just a RowNumber value to separate the values so PIVOT won't combined them and just pick the MAX and `val` is just the C2 and C3 values